# Comprobar si existe un archivo, si existe abrirlo en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

Tengo una duda sobre como es el procedimiento correcto para validar si existe o no un archivo `PDF` en una ruta especifica, me explico:
Mi objetivo principal es validar si existe el archivo `PDF`, si existe, entonces abrirlo en el navegador, si no existe, continuar con mi proceso que ya tengo, se me ocurre utilizar lo siguiente:

```
string ruta = @"C:\mi_ruta\archivo.pdf";
if (FILE.EXISTS(ruta))
{
    //entonces que me abra el archivo PDF
}
ELSE
{
    //continua mi flujo
}
```

Lo que quiero saber es como hacer la validación correcta si existe el archivo o no, si existe, abrir el `PDF`.

Cualquier ayuda me seria de mucha utilidad, y si requieren mas explicación estaré al tanto.

Comment: Cual es tu dudo como abrirlo, o si lo que pusiste es lo optimo?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez el código que puse es simplemente una idea, si hay otra soluciones de validar si existe o no el archivo bienvenida sea, y de como abrir el archivo si existe en la ruta

Comment: Revisando la respuesta de Edgar me parece que hay más consideraciones como comenta gbianchi , por ejemplo si el archivo es pdf o no existe en realidad no podrías determinar que sucedió en realidad y algo importante es que el archivo puede tener en su nombre ",pdf" y podría detectarlo como PDF lo cual es incorrecto, ejemplo : `"C:\mi_ruta\archivos\archivo.pdf.txt"` , revisa mi respuesta @eddyKroZ 
 , saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo de acuerdo a tu pregunta te anexo lo siguiente.

```
    string pdfPath = @"E:\dummy.pdf";

   if (File.Exists(pdfPath)&& pdfPath.ToUpper().Contains(".PDF"))
    {
        //Se abre el  PDF
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfPath);
    }
    else
    {
        //Si no se continua el flujo normal no le veo el caso de usar ELSE por que de todas formas seguira
    }
```

Uso el 
**pdfPath.ToUpper().Contains(".PDF")** por que como dices que solo seran PDF entonces valido que el archivo sea un PDF uso el ToUpper para volverlo a Mayuscula todo por si el archivo viene en .PDF o .pdf sea indiferente.

Saludos

Comment: perfecto, pregunta, el código que pusiste sirve igual al momento de dar click en el botón?

Comment: Ah si claro amigo, si la respuesta es la correcta marcarla como correcta por favor :D

Comment: La validacion es algo rara. si haces file.exists de un archivo *.pdf, entonces es un pdf. la validacion de que selecciono un archivo del tipo correcto deberia venir antes. Hacer File.exist y en la misma linea controlar que sea pdf no estaria correcta. Porque a la larga, porque fallo? porque no existia el archivo o porque no era un pdf?

Comment: Claro yo lo puse ahi pero pienso que el en algun momento puede cambiar el archivo no sabria

Comment: Si el "archivo" fuera `c:\miVirus.pdf.exe`, este código lo tomaría como un _pdf_ cuando evidentemente no lo es.

Comment: Si tiene razón se solucionaria con lo que agrego @Jorgesys , gracias por la observación

Answer (score 2):

Agrego otra respuesta más, porque se me hizo extraño que en ninguna de las 2 anteriores usaran la clase [`Path`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.path?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Path);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), que tiene un método que es específicamente para obtener la extensión de un archivo, evitando el uso de `Contains` o `EndsWith` (me refiero a [`Path.GetExtension(string path)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Path.GetExtension);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8).

```
const string rutaEjemplo = "D:\\Finalpdf.pdf";
//Chequeo que la extensión sea efectivamente .pdf
if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(rutaEjemplo).ToLower() == ".pdf")
{
    //Dado el caso, verifico que exista el archivo..
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(rutaEjemplo))
    {
        //Lo ejecuto.
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(rutaEjemplo);
    }
    else
    {
        //Caso que la ruta tenga la extensión correcta, pero el archivo
        //no exista en el disco
        MessageBox.Show("El archivo no existe.");
    }
}
else
{
    //Caso de que la extensión sea incorrecta.
    MessageBox.Show("El formato del archivo no es correcto.");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, entonces al utilizar la clase path para validar si el archivo realmente es un PDF, puede ser la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Esta me parece la mejor respuesta, utiliza la funcionalidad ya existente en el framework y contiene el ejemplo más completo.

Comment: @eddyKroZ mejor, así como mejor, es muy abstracto, acá en So tratamos de no hablar de mejor o peor, simplemente es otra solución que usa clase incluida en .net para hacer la comprobación en lugar de jugar con el string de la ruta

Answer (score 1):

> Mi objetivo principal es validar si existe el archivo PDF

Si tu defines que deseas validar si existe un archivo PDF, te sugiero realizar estas consideraciones.

- Determinar si el archivo es un .pdf, para esto no es solo necesario buscar ".pdf" , ya que un archivo ( ejemplo: `"C:\mi_ruta\archivos\archivo.pdf.txt"`) o directorio ( ejemplo: `"C:\mi_ruta\archivos.pdf\archivo.txt"`) puede tener la cadena ".pdf"  y no necesariamente ser un archivo .pdf.
- Se sugiere buscar si el archivo termina con la extensión `.pdf`, por lo tanto puedes usar el método `.EndsWith( )` si el archivo finaliza con `".pdf"` o también usar el método System.IO.Path.GetExtension() para definir si la extensión de la ruta es .pdf.

. esto después de realizar una "normalización" convirtiendo la ruta del archivo en minúsculas mediante `ToLower()`.

- Posteriormente si el archivo es un .pdf ahora procedes a revisar si existe mediante `File.Exists()` :

Este sería un ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código:

```
        string ruta = @"C:\mi_ruta\archivo.pdf";

        //Determina si el archivo es un PDF.

         //if (ruta.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf")) //opción 1.
         if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ruta).ToLower() == ".pdf") //opción 2.
        {
            //Determina si existe el archivo.
            if (File.Exists(ruta))
            {
                //Abre archivo .pdf
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ruta);
            }
            else
            {
                //El archivo no existe, continua sin realizar acción.
                MessageBox.Show("El archivo " + ruta + " no existe.");                    
            }
        }
        else
        {
           //El archivo no es un PDF, continua sin realizar acción.
            MessageBox.Show("El archivo " + ruta + " no es un .pdf.");
        }
```

Comment: Aprecio realmente tu ayuda, nunca había usado el .EndsWith() lo usare para mi caso, muchas gracias!!